# Public Declare Function BringWindowToTop Lib "user32" _ Alias "BringWindowToTop" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Tags: vba, ms-access

When this code:

```
Public Declare Function BringWindowToTop Lib "user32" _
Alias "BringWindowToTop" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
```

Shows the error:

> Constants, fixed-length strings, arrays, user-defined types, and Declare statements not allowed as Public members of an object module

Please help me to resolve error

Comment: The error msg tells you. `Declare` can't go in form module, it must be in code module.

Comment: Code module AKA general module, i.e. not behind form or report.

Comment: More info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46428459/declare-statement-in-win64-vba-office

Comment: In addition to ensuring that the declaration is in a standard code module, are you sure that you don't need a *PtrSafe* version of the API?

Answer (score 0):

In a **module** (not a form):

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function BringWindowToTop Lib "user32" _
        (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
#Else
    Public Declare Function BringWindowToTop Lib "user32" _
        Alias "BringWindowToTop" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
#End If
```

Comment: the first "ByVal hwnd As Long" should be "ByVal hwnd As LongPtr)" as it's an handle